Flyway Docker-Compose Windows - SQL Files Not Found
I am attempting to migrate files with Flyway to an Azure Postgres database that already contains a table. I ran the flyway migrate command with the baseline environment variable equal to true and was able to successfully create the flyway_schema_history table and baseline the database. However, I get a warning that says no migrations found, yet I have migrations in the flyway/sql folder I think I am mounting:
postgres_flyway  | Flyway OSS Edition 10.16.0 by Redgate
postgres_flyway  |
postgres_flyway  | See release notes here: https://rd.gt/416ObMi
postgres_flyway  | Schema history table "public"."flyway_schema_history" does not exist yet
postgres_flyway  | Successfully validated 0 migrations (execution time 00:00.155s)
postgres_flyway  | WARNING: No migrations found. Are your locations set up correctly?
postgres_flyway  | Creating Schema History table "public"."flyway_schema_history" with baseline ...
postgres_flyway  | Successfully baselined schema with version: 1
postgres_flyway  | Current version of schema "public": 1
postgres_flyway  | Schema "public" is up to date. No migration necessary.
postgres_flyway exited with code 0

I think the problem may be that my directory and files are not being mounted like expected. Here is my docker-compose file:
services:
  
  flyway_migration:
    image: flyway/flyway
    container_name: postgres_flyway
    environment:
      FLYWAY_PASSWORD: redacted
      FLYWAY_USER:  redacted
      FLYWAY_URL:  redacted
      FLYWAY_CONNECT_RETRIES: 60
      FLYWAY_BASELINE_ON_MIGRATE: true
    command:  migrate
    volumes:
      - //ptl-chddc02b/user/Cloud/Desktop/postgres_flyway_dev/flyway/sql/:/flyway/sql

Note, The file name of the script I am trying to migrate is higher than the baseline version of 1 and contains two underscores V2__myMigration.sql
What I have tried:

removing the slash after sql in the source section of the volume mount
wrapping the source and target in single and double quotes
I have confirmed the files have read, write and execute on my cloud desktop before I attempt to mount them
I have provided a full qualified and relative path

Thank you for your help!
